# Excel calls IRTD.ServerTerminate while there are still active RTD formulas in a sheet

Tags: c#, excel, rtd, com-server

I have a C# `RtdServer` that receives data updates from a `TCPListener`. It's runs as expected except for that at certain points when it still has active `RTD()`s in the sheet `ServerTerminate()` is called and I can't seem to figure out why.

I was of the understanding that `ServerTerminate()` is called if:

- All rtd formulae are deleted
- `ServerStart()` doesn't return 1

What other reasons are there for excel to call `ServerTerminate()` ?

**EDIT:**

Here is how I setup the `HeartBeat` mechanism:

```
public int ServerStart(IRTDUpdateEvent callback)
{
    callback.HeartbeatInterval = 60000; // 1 min HB 
    _callback = callback;  
    // Other setup ...
    return 1;
}
```

This is the `HeartBeat` code

```
public int Heartbeat()
{
    _log.Info("HB called...");
    return 1;
}
```

From above, I expect to see calls to `HeartBeat` every 60 seconds (60Kms) but I see no logging of this. I'm stumped - any ideas??

Comment: What about `Heartbeat`? I'd expect its failures to be treated similar to `ServerStart`.

Comment: HB code is added above. How often should I expect this to be called?

Comment: Server Terminate is called when no more topics are required. I would log the new IDs coming in every time ConnectData is called, and then log them again on DisconnectData. You should be able to see if Excel thinks there are no more topics left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found that excel will restart a com server (rtd) if the UI thread is heavily under strain.

I was able to reproduce this 'server restart' by aggressively using the keyboard shortcuts: `shift+▲▼◀▼` to navigate in a sheet that is heavily loaded with active RTDs. Although this isn't a reliable method of forcing excel to restart the server it works often enough to test. You can try to reproduce the com server restart by doing the following:

- write 50K+ of your RTDs to a sheet
- start firing updates at your RTD from it's source (the higher the data throughput, the more likely excel will capitulate and restart the com server)
- set the `Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval = 0//` ([update whenever
  possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140060%28v=office.10%29.aspx#odc_xlrtdfaq_howconfigrtdthrottle))
- when up and running, navigate frantically around the sheet using the
  keyboard shortcuts (`shift+▲▼◀▼`)

This will *likely* cause excel to restart the RTD and in doing so, first call `ServerTerminate()` (regardless of how many RTDs exist in the sheet) and then call `ServerStart()` effectively restarting the server which explains the behavior noted.

The server restart resets all of the data in your RTD implementation so you should consider this as a complete reset so any subscriptions should be reset also.

Hth!